# How to find $\int \sqrt{a^2-x^2} dx$, where $a$ is a constant

Tags: integration

How to find $$\int \sqrt{a^2-x^2} dx\;,$$ where $a$ is a constant?

It appears to be $$\frac{\pi a}{2}\;,$$ but how do I get there?

Comment: Let $x=a\sin\,u$...

Comment: @J.M. how do I know to use that substitution?

Comment: Do you want a definite integral?

Comment: Your integral is an indefinite integral, so its value cannot be a specific number. Presumably it’s supposed to be a definite integral; what are the limits of integration? I suspect that they’re $-a$ and $a$, in which case the correct answer is $\pi a^2/2$.

Comment: To see why you would use the substitution $x=a\sin u$, look at the section on trig substitutions in any standard calculus text; this is a standard example.

Comment: Jiew, you know the relationship $\sin^2 u+\cos^2 u=1$, yes?

Comment: Square roots are usually nasty when taking antiderivatives. You try to make a substitution that will allow you to get rid of the radical.  Here, using a slight modification of $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$, or $\cos^2\theta=1-\sin^2\theta$, will allow you to do that.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Yes its an definite integral, but I will need to find the indefinite integral first?

Comment: When you see a difference of squares, draw a right triangle that it suggests, then choose a trigonometric substitution corresponding to that triangle.  Similar advice for a sum of squares.

Comment: "but I will need to find the indefinite integral first?" - of course, but the result of indefinite integration is a *function*, not a *constant*.

Comment: Yes, you’ll need to find the antiderivative, but it’s still better to state the problem correctly. (Actually, if the limits are $-a$ and $a$ you *don’t* need to find the antiderivative: $y=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ is the upper half of a circle of radius $a$ centred at the origin, and $\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$ is the area between that half-circle and the $x$-axis, or half the area of a circle of radius $a$.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of finding the definite integral is to consider the shape of the graph.  If $y = \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ then $y^2=a^2-x^2$, so $x^2+y^2=a^2$.  Apply the Pythagorean theorem: that's the equation of a circle of radius $a$.  $y = \pm\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ is the whole circle; $y = \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ is the top half of the circle.  If you know that the area of the whole circle is $\pi a^2$, then the area of the top half is
$$
\int_{-a}^a \sqrt{a^2-x^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi a^2}{2}.
$$

Generally, if you have
$$
a^2-x^2
$$
in an integral, you can use $x = a\sin\theta$ and $dx = a\cos\theta\,d\theta$, and then $a^2-x^2$ becomes $a^2\cos^2\theta$.

If you have
$$
a^2 + x^2
$$
then you can use $x = a\tan\theta$, $dx = a\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$, $a^2+x^2=a^2\sec^2\theta$.

If you have
$$
x^2 - a^2
$$
then you can use $x=a\sec\theta$, $dx=a\sec\theta\tan\theta\,d\theta$, $x^2 - a^2 = a^2\tan^2\theta$.

Comment: 3:21:45 versus 3:21:35. =)

Answer (score 2):

It might be enlightening for you to think the following.

The function to integrate is $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}=y$.

This gives that

$$y^2+x^2=a^2$$

I really hope you know this is the equation for a circle of radius $a$ centered at $(0,0)$. Since you're integrating from $-a$ to $a$, you're calculating the area of half a circle of radius $a$. This means that the integral

$$\int_{-a}^{a} \sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx $$

gives the area of half a circle of radius $a$, which is $\dfrac 1 2\pi a^2$.